# rabbitMQ is not consumming my messages

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, amqp

I installed rabbitmq-server and amqp-tools. My consumer starts ok with this parameter:

```
# amqp-consume -s 127.0.0.1:5672 -e "amq.topic" --vhost "/" -r "worker1" --username=guest --password=guest -d onmessage.sh
Server provided queue name: amq.gen-gzncPpcYr0f1s8HfI-A5cW
```

My publisher can send the messages and I can see it at the console and web browser:

```
# amqp-publish -s 127.0.0.1:5672 -e "amq.topic" -r "worker1" --vhost="/" --username=guest --password=guest -b "this is a test message"
# rabbitmqctl list_queuesListing queues ...
amq.gen-gzncPpcYr0f1s8HfI-A5cW  3
...done.
```

The scrip onmessage.sh just read a line and echo it on screen. But the consumer is not comsuming the messages. Why?

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare a queue in the consumer. you should add:

```
-q "my_queue"
```

like this:

```
# amqp-consume -s 127.0.0.1:5672 -e "amq.topic" -q "my_queue" --vhost "/" -r "worker1" --username=guest --password=guest -d onmessage.sh
```

the -e declares the exchange.

Comment: it is not necessary. The rabbitMQ creates its on queue (amq.gen-gzncPpcYr0f1s8HfI-A5cW) . I solved using /bin/bash before the script.